# Meteor collection find() throws exception when 'limit' added as option

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I use the this publish function in my meteor-angular app (created following [this tutorial](http://info.meteor.com/blog/whatsapp-with-meteor-angular-and-ionic)):

```
Meteor.publish('organization', function (name) {
    return Orgs.find({category: name});
}
```

I'm working with a production db which has many records. As such, it takes almost a minute to complete. ATM it is sufficient that the client retrieve the first 10 items, which can be randomly selected. Since it is impractical to send all records and filter those on the client side, I would like to limit the number of records which are offered in `Meteor.publish()`.

According to [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find), `limit` can be used:

```
Meteor.publish('organization', function (name) {
    return Orgs.find({category: name}, {limit: 10});
}
```

Problem is, when this runs the server throws an exception:

```
I20160104-19:33:13.397(2)? organization publish b20884d3-90cb-49d7-9acd-3c4bd140e24b
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)? Exception from sub organization id zaAjjJKg3pNnf7ZGP Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf or Match.Optional validation
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at check (packages/check/packages/check.js:41:1)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at [object Object]._.extend._getFindOptions (packages/mongo/packages/mongo.js:3653:1)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at [object Object]._.extend.find (packages/mongo/packages/mongo.js:3689:1)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at [object Object]._handler (server/publications.js:11:1)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler (livedata_server.js:1023:17)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription (livedata_server.js:842:9)
I20160104-19:33:13.398(2)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub (livedata_server.js:614:12)
I20160104-19:33:13.399(2)?     at livedata_server.js:548:43
I20160104-19:33:13.399(2)? Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]
I2
```

Am I doing it the right way? Any advice or ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you also provide a sort option with the limit option?

Comment: Can you `console.log(name)` and see if it is ever undefined?

Comment: @BrendanTurner: the error still occurs when adding the sort option

Comment: @PatrickMencias-lewis: added the log, `name` is never undefined. The server throw occurs when it's a non-zero string. The find returns a valid cursor if not for the `limit` option

Comment: add `check(name, String);` before return

Comment: @AdamWolski yup did that, still throws. Seems like the problem is with the value assigned to `limit`. It's not getting accepted by `check.js`

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Yay, found a fix:

```
meteor update pbastowski:angular-babel
```

Then saw:

```
pbastowski:angular-babel  upgraded from 1.0.8 to 1.0.9
```

The server exception disappeared, it's that simple! 
Thank you all for the comments, time to happily-meteor again ;-)

*FYI I confirmed the fix by downgrading `pbastowski:angular-babel` back to 1.0.8 and seeing the crash*